# $('#basicModal').modal({literal} {keyboard:false} {/literal});} Smarty template , syntax error?

Tags: javascript, templates, smarty

anyone knows how to fix the syntax error regarding this line?

```
$('#basicModal').modal({literal} {keyboard:false} {/literal});
```

I am using Dreamweaver, it says syntax error.
In browser, when I inspect, error says " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" at end of

So i use JSHint and the problem of this line is this:
Eight warnings
486 'object short notation' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).
486 Expected ')' and instead saw '{'.
486 Missing semicolon.
486 Label 'keyboard' on false statement.
486 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
486 Missing semicolon.
486 Unclosed regular expression.
486 Unrecoverable syntax error. (13% scanned).

It all stated to the code above.
I am very new to this smarty and wonder what went wrong?
Can anyone helps me?

Comment: Because smarty templates aren't JavaScript and it makes no sense to run it through a JavaScript validator.

Comment: Well, that is true to not used JSHint, but i figure out the errror was I imported Javascript twice. and alos, found out using VSCode is better than dreamweaver. Once i changed to VSCode, my file open in browser works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the error was I imported Javascript twice. and also, found out using VSCode is better than dreamweaver. Once i changed to VSCode, my file open in browser works fine.